# Convert Path in to editable Shape Illustrator 22

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, text-on-path

Illustrator newbie here - I downloaded an AI file with of a heart that is a single layer/single path as you can see here:

[image]

What I want to do is fill this with text - I know you can use envelope distort, but it's not having the intended effect. This technique works if I draw say a circle; as this has a "stroke" and a "fill". The heart shape is a single path and I can't interact with the "middle" which is what I think the issue is.

I think I need to convert this path into 2 shapes; effectively an "outside" heart. and the inside heart which is in white at the moment. I could then fill this with text while leaving the blue outline heart intact.

I don't even know what to google - I tried converting to a compound path and a shape but it just fails/doesn't do anything.

Any guidance appreciated.

thanks

Comment: Judging by your attempt to edit this question, it seems you have accidentally made two user accounts on this site. Stack Exchange does not support more than one account per user on a site. In case your accounts interact (upvoting your own posts, for example), they are liable to be deleted. Please go to our [help section](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) and contact SE to have this issue fixed.

Comment: Please be aware that you can *always* comment on your own posts, but you need to log in with the correct account for the site to recognise you as the post creator.

Answer (score 2):

1. Your object has overlapping paths, so you need to fix that before continuing
2. Select the heart, and in the Pathfinder, hit the *Unite* button to turn it into a compound path with a distinct inner and outer path, with no overlaps.
3. Copy <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and Paste in Front <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>. Click *Object > Compound Path > Release* or use the shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>. Select and delete the outer path, leaving the inner path and the copy of the heart graphic behind. Now you can type inside the inner path using the text tool.

In the example below, I have filled the inside of the heart grey so you can see it's a separate shape.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Select the shape and use the **Shape Builder Tool**

[image: Shape Builder Tool]

<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> Win, click each part of the shape.

[image]